# how i integrate html text editor in windows application?

Tags: c#, html, text-editor

how i integrate html text editor in windows application?

Comment: Not much different to your last: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414786/

Comment: Marc, it is an improvement, and Amit did not get a real chance to edit the previous one, did he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option would be to use a commercial syntax highlighting package, such as [Actipro SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx).

You can just use a RichTextBox and do it yourself, but it is going to be more difficult to make this seem polished.  There are some articles, such as the [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx), which show how to extend RichTextBox for custom editing and coloring. That would be a good starting point, if you want to make your own.

If you just want a place people can type HTML in, but don't need coloring, syntax checking, etc - you can just use a RichTextBox and let the user type in the HTML.